# How I can add web link into jira issue with jira python

Tags: python, web, hyperlink, jira

I want to add a web link into link session.

I know to add a issue link with that :

```
issue = jira.issue(issue_source)
issue2 = jira.issue(issue_destination)
jira.create_issue_link('Duplicate', issue, issue2, None)
```

but I don't know to add web link,

I also try, that but I get an error :

```
jira.add_simple_link(args.js, {
    "object": {
        "url":"http://www.mycompany.com/support?id=1",
        "title":"Crazy customer support issue"
    }
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Where exactly you want to add web link? Please describe.

Comment: I want to add into link section a web link, whick we can click in the utr describe and to go directly into remote link.
Just next to issue link of jira issue